# Oauth 2.0 - Redirect URL takes user to the canvas page on my website and not to the iframe on Facebook

Tags: facebook, redirect, oauth-2.0

I have looked around and around for hours now and messed about with different pieces of code and I am at a loss.

I am only a begginner at PHP so I am learning it as I go along. I get how authorisation works and I have managed to get the app authorised, just once the app has been authorised the application redirects the user to the full canvas page on my website instead of displaying my canvas page in the iframe within Facebook.

I can't for the life of me work out how to change this so the redirect redirects to the iframe and not my website.

I would really appreciate some help on this matter.

(P.s. I know there are similar topics to this and I have read quite a few and have found nothing that has helped me solve my problem)

Many Thanks
Scott

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get an undefined index for signed_request in my facebook app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7534241/why-do-i-get-an-undefined-index-for-signed-request-in-my-facebook-app)

Comment: Thanks for that, I clearly didn't look hard enough. The information in that post helped me solve my problem. Thanks again for your help.

However, it brought up another problem, when you are logged out of Facebook and click on an application, it goes to a login screen to authenticate the user, But after this login screen, if the user has already allowed the application to access their information, a page appears that says 'The URL was not found on the server'. I am continuing to look for a solution, but if anyone has any ideas I would appreciate them.